# How to create this kind of graph with R

Tags: r, ggplot2, graph

I'm trying to reproduce this graph :

[image: STATS GRAPH]

I find here : https://www.stats.com/industry-analysis-articles/salah-out-of-form-or-out-of-position/

But all I've managed to do is :

[image: MY GRAPH]

With this code :

```
ggplot(A[Position == "Central midfielder right",], 
    aes(x = variable ,y = value, fill = variable)) + 
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = "dodge") + 
  coord_polar()
```

Comment: Are you trying to replicate all elements exactly, or just certain ones? That is a very customized graphic, so it would be a big job to replicate exactly. For one, it's not using a polar transformation but rather an octagon.

Comment: If you were to go polar, there are some links in here for Plotly and ggplot. https://community.rstudio.com/t/how-can-i-generate-this-kind-of-polar-chart-in-r-studio/2158

Comment: Does it have to be done in R? Doing this in D3.js would be somewhat trivial

Comment: I would like to be able to reproduce the spirit of the graph not necessarily reproduce it exactly. Thanks @JonnyPhelps I will take a look. Also yes I would like to do it with.